# Netbeans: Customize Toolbars in Mac Sierra 10.12.4 Not Working

Tags: macos, netbeans, toolbar

I am trying to customize my toolbar in Netbeans on a MacBook Pro running Sierra 10.12.4.

I can 'add a custom toolbar' and name it, but when I try to drag and drop the desired icons into the bar, they don't get added, don't even register as hovering behavior when attempting it.

Works fine on my PC but not on my Mac.

Is this a bug or am I missing a step, or it just doesn't work on Mac?

Comment: Have you been able to resolve it? Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: No, I should probably submit a bug to the Netbeans org.